# Extracting cookies using Selenium (Python) from an iFrame

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, iframe

I am able to get cookies from the website just fine. But I am interested in the cookies which the Chatbot is using for example there are chatbot websites like: `<www.kinguin.net>` or `<www.multibankfx.com>` or `<coschedule.com>`

If we go on to these websites and 'inspect element' them and then see under the cookies for secure.livechat.inc (this is the chatbot) there will be 1 or 2 cookies as shown in the figure below

[Here in this image, I am looking into the cookies of the chatbot on the website called <www.kinguin.net> and we can see one cookie there, i.e. "__livechat"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMK7w.png)

So this cookie is what I want to automate and extract using the selenium.

**my following code return all cookies on the website but "_livechat" is missing**

```
import os, sys, json, codecs, subprocess, requests, time, string
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
host = 'kinguin.net'
driver.get("https://"+host)
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for item in cookies:
    print(item['name'])
```

**taking it further, my following code goes into the iFrame of the chatbot and get cookies but return null**

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
elementID = driver.find_element_by_id('chat-widget')
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for item in cookies:
    print(item['name'])
```

@ble Thanks alot - the way you suggest is helpful only for this particular website which is not what I want. I am sorry if I could not explain it clearly in my earlier query but I want a generic solution for a large scale website dataset.

For example, if we look at <www.ebanx.com> here the chatbot is different and hence I will search it by
`elementID = driver.find_element_by_id('hubspot-messages-iframe-container')`

and if I use your code after this `driver.switch_to.frame(elementID)`

it gives me the error

**NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame**

Answer (score 0):

With this line of code you found iframe element:

```
elementID = driver.find_element_by_id('chat-widget')
```

Use this to switch to that iframe and you will be able to collect cookies with code you wrote

```
driver.switch_to.frame(elementID)
```

After you finish, switch to default content with

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

There are more iframes on that page. The easiest approach is to find element by using unique identifier, such as 'id' or 'name' and store it in variable e.g. 'elementID'. I suggest renaming it to 'iframe_element' because it is not ID, you just got the element by ID.
Also, avoid search by index (`driver.switch_to.frame(0)`) if there are not so many iframes on page (https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html)

Comment: Thanks alot - the way you suggest is helpful only for this particular website which is not what I want. I am sorry if I could not explain it clearly in my earlier query but I want a generic solution for a large scale website dataset. For example, if we look at <www.ebanx.com> here the chatbot is different and hence I will search it by '''elementID = driver.find_element_by_id('hubspot-messages-iframe-container')''' and if I use your code after this '''driver.switch_to.frame(elementID)''' it gives me the error **NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame**

Comment: can you make a dictionary e.g. dictionary={'kinguin.net':'chat-widget', ...} for all websites and then 
use elementID = driver.find_element_by_id(dictionary[host])

Comment: This is not the issue - the keyword is not the issue here, the issue is what I mentioned above that it does not work for all websites (I have a million websites to scrape)

Comment: I tought it might work for you if you define it like this `dictionary={'kinguin.net':'chat-widget', 'ebanx.com':''hubspot-messages-iframe-container', ...}` for all websites
and go to www.kinguin.net, since you wrote `host = 'kinguin.net'` when it comes to that line `elementID = driver.find_element_by_id(dictionary[host])` it would read it as `elementID = driver.find_element_by_id('chat-widget'])`.. if that doesn't suit for you, stick to `driver.switch_to.frame(0)`. hope someone else will be able to help you